# kafka listener not being able to consume messages unless written otherwise

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

**LEVEL II EXPERIMENT**

If i use `return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer());` the consumer does not fetch any message.

But - if i use the following the consumer works

```
JsonDeserializer<ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage.class);
               deserializer.setRemoveTypeHeaders(false);
               deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
               deserializer.setUseTypeMapperForKey(true);
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage>(props, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer)
```

My sole aim is to make a single `ConsumerFactory` to receive three different type of payload such as `A.class`, `B.class` and `C.class`

Thanks.

---

**PLEASE DO NOT SEE BELOW**

The kafka listener is not being able to consume messages unless written in a different way.

**Listener 1** - **Not being able to consume messages** if i use type mapping (token:type) that is a standalone producer application a standalone consumer application

```
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {

             JsonDeserializer<Object> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
Map<String, Object> deserProps = new HashMap<>();
             deserProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, applicationConfig.getTypeMapping());

             Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
             props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, applicationConfig.getKafkaGroupId());
             props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, LATEST);
             props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, FALSE);
             props.put("security.protocol", applicationConfig.getKafkaSslProtocol());
             props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, applicationConfig.getKafkaSslTrustStoreLocation());
             props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
       props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonDeserializer.class);
             props.put(ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, applicationConfig.getInterceptorClassConfig());
             props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");

             jsonDeserializer.configure(deserProps, false);
             return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), jsonDeserializer);
       }

       @Bean
       public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
             ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
             factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
             factory.setErrorHandler(new CustomSeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
             factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
       factory.getContainerProperties().setAssignmentCommitOption(AssignmentCommitOption.NEVER);
             factory.setConcurrency(2);
             return factory;
       }



    @KafkaListener(id = "welcomeConsumerIdOne", autoStartup = "false", topics = "#{appConfig.getWelcomeConfirmedEventTopic()}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
           public void consumeWelcomeMessage(ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage message, @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders, Acknowledgment ack) {
//message received
```

}

**Listener 2** - **Able to consume messages** without any type mapping.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "bev3_welcome_confirmed_topic_dev", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
       public void consumePublishedEvents(ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage message) {
             System.out.println("consumed message: "+message);             
       }

    @Bean
           public ConsumerFactory<String, ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage> consumerFactory() {
    
                 JsonDeserializer<ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage.class);
               deserializer.setRemoveTypeHeaders(false);
               deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
               deserializer.setUseTypeMapperForKey(true);
               
               
                 Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
;
                 props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
                 props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, deserializer);
                 props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, applicationConfig.getKafkaGroupId());
                 props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, LATEST);
                 props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, TRUE);
                 props.put("security.protocol", applicationConfig.getKafkaSslProtocol());
                 props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, applicationConfig.getKafkaSslTrustStoreLocation());
                 props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
                 
                 return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage>(props, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
           }
    
           /**
           * Kafka Listener container factory
           * 
            * @return ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
           * 
            */
           @Bean
           public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
                 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConsumerEnrollmentSyncMessage>();
                 factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
                 return factory;
           }
```

I am using `LATEST`

I am not too sure of the cause of this problem. Is there a problem with the `group-id` or is there anything has to be fixed on `kafka-broker` end. Tried changing the `listener-id` and `group-id` but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show your configuration and any error logs. "not able to consume" is insufficient information.

Comment: Hello Gary. I have added the consumer configuration details above. No error logs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

Before 2.8, when instantiating the deserializer yourself, you had to fully configure it yourself; the consumer properties were not applied.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1907

Adding the deserializer class to the properties is redundant because you are supplying an instance directly to the factory.

In any case, this makes no sense:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, deserializer);
```

it must be a class name or class, not an instance.

Comment: I am using `spring-kafka 2.3.7`

Comment: That is no longer supported https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support - with that version, you either need to configure it completely, programmatically, or call the `configure()` method, passing in the config props.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have done some work in my `LEVEL II experiment(Top of this page)` Please could you look into the above and suggest ? Thanks

Comment: `>the consumer does not fetch any message` - that makes no sense; you should see errors if it is misconfigured. If you are using `@KafkaListener`, consider using a `ByteArrayDeserializer` and let the framework determine the target type from the method signature - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.3/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion . If you mean the same listener needs to get A, B, and C, then we need to figure out what's wrong with your environment. Please post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Sure I will post a MCRE. I wanted to have a single `ConsumerFactory` with 3 different `Topic` and 3 `@KafkaListener`

Comment: Sounds like the message converter solution is a better/simpler fit for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242825/discussion-between-nihar-and-gary-russell).